# slideToggle по горизонтали

Tags: jquery

Есть ли в jQuery функция, эквивалентная slideToggle только чтобы блок разворачивался по горизонтали (слева на право)?

Comment: Конечно есть

Comment: Соответственный вопрос, какая?

Comment: Её нужно самому навоять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так по горизонтали разворачивать/сворачивать

```
$('#element').animate({width:'toggle'}, 350)
```